# Node Serverless Webpack not working on Lambda

Tags: node.js, lambda, webpack, babeljs, serverless-framework

I have a situation where my `serverless-webpack` code works locally (using `serverless-offline`), but when when I deploy to Lambda, I get a 502.

[image: Hello World screen shot]

[image: Internal server error screen shot]

It's a fairly simple "Hello World" Node.js application, but I've thrown in some twists as I'm trying to build a starter kit for a "real" app. As with any real JavaScript application, I'd like to code in ES.next (i.e. ES7, Babel, etc) so I'm building with `serverless-webpack` which supports Babel. I'm using `babel-preset-node6` (instead of `babel-preset-es2015` as shown in many examples) and `babel-preset-stage-2` (but that shouldnt' matter).

I'm also moving the http handler logic (i.e. `handler,js`) away from the hello world code (i.e. `src/helloWorld.js`). You know, separation of concerns and all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
The complete code is on [Github](https://github.com/donavon/serverless-hello-world).

Output from my deploy is:

```
$ npm run deploy

> serverless-hello-world@1.0.0 deploy /Users/dwest15/Projects/serverless-hello-world
> serverless deploy --verbose

Serverless: Bundling with Webpack...
Time: 1668ms
     Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
handler.js  3.3 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./handler.js 545 bytes {0} [built]
   [1] ./src/helloWorld.js 170 bytes {0} [built]
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service .zip file to S3 (1.19 KB)...
Serverless: Validating template...
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
CloudFormation - UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - serverless-hello-world-dev
CloudFormation - UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Lambda::Function - HelloLambdaFunction
CloudFormation - UPDATE_COMPLETE - AWS::Lambda::Function - HelloLambdaFunction
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Lambda::Version - HelloLambdaVersionMwMvIa4C7w8VnfGwQ5XC5WckkAFmXlqS8zQstBBMPI
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::Lambda::Version - HelloLambdaVersionMwMvIa4C7w8VnfGwQ5XC5WckkAFmXlqS8zQstBBMPI
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::Lambda::Version - HelloLambdaVersionMwMvIa4C7w8VnfGwQ5XC5WckkAFmXlqS8zQstBBMPI
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment - ApiGatewayDeployment1503159056152
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment - ApiGatewayDeployment1503159056152
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment - ApiGatewayDeployment1503159056152
CloudFormation - UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - serverless-hello-world-dev
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::Lambda::Version - HelloLambdaVersionhJfJUbfRfskBMTrUXv0UKoa0RHCi3U3mGJ5NcfkxP4
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment - ApiGatewayDeployment1503157776493
CloudFormation - DELETE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment - ApiGatewayDeployment1503157776493
CloudFormation - UPDATE_COMPLETE - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - serverless-hello-world-dev
Serverless: Stack update finished...
Service Information
service: serverless-hello-world
stage: dev
region: us-east-1
stack: serverless-hello-world-dev
api keys:
  None
endpoints:
  GET - https://bybx7hbzdh.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/hello
functions:
  hello: serverless-hello-world-dev-hello

Stack Outputs
HelloLambdaFunctionQualifiedArn: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:674804044156:function:serverless-hello-world-dev-hello:7
ServiceEndpoint: https://bybx7hbzdh.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev
ServerlessDeploymentBucketName: serverless-hello-world-d-serverlessdeploymentbuck-nnys203g15q

Serverless: Removing old service versions...
```

Comment: What do the AWS logs say?

Comment: The logs said that I was doing something wrong. :) It turns out that I was returning an object literal for `body`, but Lambda requires a string. I wrapped my result body in `JSON.stringify` and it works fine. Doh!

Comment: @donavon You have to stringify your result if you're using lambda-proxy (serverless default). It is documented in https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#simple-http-endpoint.

Comment: @donavon After stringifying your `body` and making it work on Lambda, does it continue to work with serverless-offline?